# Efficient way to store user records in a file in java

Tags: java, csv, javafx

I need to store user details in a file, efficiently. Should I use different file for every record , or I should append all records in a single file.
which extension is best among these , .txt , .bin , .csv.
Or any other suggestion?

Comment: Can you precise what you mean by efficiently. Also, without any code, structure or class we cannot help much.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I use different file for every record:

No, usually not

> or I should append all records in a single file

Yes, in most cases

> which extension is best among these , .txt , .bin , .csv. ?

- bin for binary files
- csv for text based comma separated file which have one record in each line (like excell tabel)
- txt only when human readable

otherwise any extension you want, eg. ".dat"

Answer (score 0):

I have created one an app in FX that needs to store locally user inputs and details. I used XML file with JAXB (you can use JAXP too but it is somewhat outdated). Consider your details as a database. After that, with JAXB it is very easy and fast to store/load data from a local XML file